# Как подключить веб-камеру в vr очка через unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, web-camera, vr

Всем привет! Помогите подключить веб-камеру к очкам виртуальной реальности (vive) через unity

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: Подозреваю что нужно для начала вывести на plain изображение с вебки, а потом плейн закрепить напротив камеры очков

Comment: @aepot, у меня получилось подключить саму веб-камеру к юнити, но показать это изображение в виртуальных очках не получается

Comment: @Andrew, спасибо, попробую